# How to install Foma fst library

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install the [foma](https://fomafst.github.io/) package on my Xubuntu 16.04 system.

According to the site, when I type `sudo apt install foma` it should be installed. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Here's the output when I type it:

```
sudo apt install foma
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package foma
```

What should I do to install the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site seems to be out of date or incorrect. [The package is called `foma-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/foma-bin), so you should be able to manage with:

```
sudo apt install foma-bin
```

If that fails, ensure the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) is enabled (it should be, by default).